# php: iterate recordset - easier way?

Tags: php, database, loops, recordset

i've just changed from ASP to php and i'm a bit confused about the way php is handling recordsets.
i'd like to know if there's an easier way to iterate a recordset by creating a php class.
here's the ASP syntax to show what i mean:

```
sq = "select * from myData"
set rs = db.execute(sq)
do while not rs.eof
    response.write rs("name")  // output data (response.write = echo)
    rs.movenext
loop
```

any ideas? 
thanks

Comment: what DBMS this recordset belongs to?

Comment: You'd use a `foreach` loop typically. There's lots of tutorials that you can follow.

Comment: @Blair not so typically I'd say.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - I missed the php class part. I just just talking about the existing (asp) code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd pretty much do the same thing...

```
$sql = "select * from myData";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //executes query
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //will automatically return false when out of records
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a function contains word `fetch` in it's name.
E.g. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `$pdo->fetchAll()`.

Most of database API functions in PHP returns some sort of pointer variable called "resource", which can be passed to the fetch-family function, like this:

```
$res = mysql_query();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

However, some of them (like PDO's [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method) returns but regular PHP array, which you can iterate using as regular `foreach` operator.